# Searching for multiple partial phrases so that one original phrase can not match multiple search phrases

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, search-algorithms, strings, search-trees

Given a predefined set of phrases, I'd like to perform a search based on user's query. For example, consider the following set of phrases:

```
index      phrase
-----------------------------------------
0          Stack Overflow
1          Math Overflow
2          Super User
3          Webmasters
4          Electrical Engineering
5          Programming Jokes
6          Programming Puzzles
7          Geographic Information Systems
```

The expected behaviour is:

```
query         result
------------------------------------------------------------------------
s             Stack Overflow, Super User, Geographic Information Systems
web           Webmasters
over          Stack Overflow, Math Overflow
super u       Super User
user s        Super User
e e           Electrical Engineering
p             Programming Jokes, Programming Puzzles
p p           Programming Puzzles
```

To implement this behaviour [I used a trie](https://github.com/moroshko/autosuggest-trie). Every node in the trie has an array of indices (empty initially).

To insert a phrase to the trie, I first break it to words. For example, `Programming Puzzles` has `index = 6`. Therefore, I add `6` to all the following nodes:

```
p
pr
pro
prog
progr
progra
program
programm
programmi
programmin
programming
pu
puz
puzz
puzzl
puzzle
puzzles
```

The problem is, when I search for the query `prog p`, I first get a list of indices for `prog` which is `[5, 6]`. Then, I get a list of indices for `p` which is `[5, 6]` as well. Finally, I calculate the intersection between the two, and return the result `[5, 6]`, which is obviously wrong (should be `[6]`).

How would you fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's fix some names. Let $q_1, \dots, q_k$ be the query strings and $w_1, \dots, w_n$ the existing phrases. Denote with $w_{i,1}, \dots, w_{i,k_i}$ the words contained in phrase $w_i$, and with $a \sqsubseteq b$ the relation "$a$ is a prefix of $b$".

Currently, you have implemented to obtain this:

$\qquad\displaystyle \{ i \in [1..n] \mid \forall j \in [1..k]\ \exists j' \in [1..k_i].\ q_j \sqsubseteq w_{i,j'}\}$.

Note how the $\exists$-operator does not preclude the same $j'$ for multiple $j$, and that's your problem (as far as I can tell). What you want is

$\qquad\displaystyle \{ i \in [1..n] \mid \exists J = \{j_1, \dots, j_k\} \subseteq [1..k_i]\ \forall j \in [1..k].\ q_j \sqsubseteq w_{i,j_j}\}$.

One way to implement this is to go with the double-indexing I used to describe the problem formally: each node gets the set of labels $(i,j)$ if its corresponding string is a prefix of $w_{i,j}$. Now, $i$ is a match if

- every $q_l$ leads to a node with label $(i,\_)$ and
- the second components of these labels are pairwise distinct (if there are multiple $(i,\_)$ for a single $q_l$, one has to check if there is a choice fulfilling the condition).

In your example, instead of just adding `6` to all these nodes you list, you'd add `(5,1)` and `(6,1)` to the prefixes of `programming`, and `(6,2)` to those of `puzzles`. Now, `prog p` gives you `(5,1), (6,1)` for `prog` and `(5,1), (6,1), (6,2)` for `p`; you can exclude `5` because it has the same second component for both query phrases whereas `6` has a "valid" match with `(6,1)` and `(6,2)`.

Comment: Appreciate how you formalised the question and the proposed solution. All looks good except the last sentence. How would you decide if it's a valid match? I tried to formalise this last bit in [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/42341/33455).